# window.innerHeight in Angular 6 Animations does not work

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am a bit confusing about my issue because it will run locally but does not run on server.

The idea is to animate a table from state **increased** to the state **reduced** (and other way round) with `window.innerHeight` minus static value (e.g. 150) and on the same time a detail card moves in or out the frame.

**app.ts:**

```
animations: [
trigger('BodyDetailsInOut', [
  state('in', style({ transform: 'translateY(0)' })),
  state('out', style({ transform: 'translateY(100%)' })),
  transition('out => in', [style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(100%)' }), animate('400ms ease-in')]),
  transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-out')),
]),
trigger('TableReduceIncrease', [
  state('reduced', style({ height: window.innerHeight - 750 + "px" })),
  state('increased', style({height: window.innerHeight - 150 + "px" })),
  transition('increased => reduced', [style({ height: window.innerHeight - 150 + "px" }), animate('400ms ease-in')]),
  transition('reduced => increased', animate('400ms ease-out')),
])]
```

However, it works fine locally but on server the table does not reduce.

In the Console a warning occured like:

> Invalid keyframe value for property height: -150px

Btw.. is it probably a server-setting issue or completly not allowed to set height like this?

Comment: The height of the window can be get with `height: 100vh`, which means "viewport height". You can make calculations with `height: calc(100vh - 750px)`, but it would work on recent browsers only.

Comment: And when you talk about your server, are you talking about server-side rendering ?

Comment: Finally, you could take advantage of the `position: fixed` and set the style as follows : `box-sizing: content-box; padding: 375px 0px; max-height: 100vh;`.

Comment: @trichetriche: i mean, if that project is deployed on the server and locally is "on debug-modus"

Comment: Probably an issue with runtime then. Did you try my other two solutions ? The second one should fullfil your need

Comment: @trichetriche: i am on it.. :) .. Well, it works fine on chrome! Thank you very much!

Comment: I tested it on Chrome, Edge and Firefox. Every Browser shows it different. On Chrome it runs best. Little adjustment will solve this problem.